# Désolé du retard vs. Désolé pour le retard

Tags: expressions, différence

Which one is used most often? And which of the two is more formal?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=D%C3%A9sol%C3%A9+du+retard%2CD%C3%A9sol%C3%A9+pour+le+retard&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3 — « Se désoler *de* » → *Désolé **de/du*** … ;  « Être désolé *de/que* » → *Désolé **que** cette erreur ait été commise : désolé **de** cette situation*. Le ***pour*** est moins formel.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40643/1109

Comment: My issue with this question is that starting a sentence with "Désolé" is already not formal.

Answer (score 2):

I would preferably use

> ```
> désolé de + "infinitif" (je suis désolé d'être arrivé en retard)
> ```

and

> désolé pour + noun/pronoun (je suis désolé pour mon retard)

But this is not a strict rule (désolé de + noun is also correct as far as I know) and both are formal.

As a remark, it is more formal to say "Je suis désolé.e ..." than "Désolé.e ...")

Answer (score 1):

Both do work, you would use **pour** for day to day speech and **du** for the formal one.

Answer (score 0):

You can say both.
Ex: Désolé pour le retard que j’ai eu ce matin.
Ex: Désolé du retard que j’ai eu ce matin.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to me that there are any rules.

In familiar language (with friends, family), we will use one or the other. In a more formal context, we will rather use "de". However, in either case, we are sorry for someone: "Je suis désolé pour Paul qui vient de...".

The problem with "désolé pour" comes from the rest of the sentence. For example, if I replace "retard" with "la mort de quelqu'un" (someone's death):

- "Je suis désolé de la mort de Paul."
- "Je suis désolé pour la mort de Paul."

The second sentence sounds less good. So even if there is no particular rule, "de" will be preferred.

In any case, as the others have specified, in a formal context, we will not use "Désolé" but "Je suis désolé". And in the case of "retard", we will instead use "Veuillez m'excuser de mon retard".

Answer (score -1):

I've been scratching my head for a minute trying to figure out an actual difference between the two, but even in terms of formality, I'd have to say that **both are in effect perfectly equivalent**. Use whichever one, no sweat.

Comment: Peut-être dans la vie courante, mais formellement ils ne sont pas équivalents du tout et dépendent du contexte https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43179/848 et *désolé·e* ne doit pas commencer une phrase écrite lorsqu'il s'agit de présenter ses condoléances ou ses excuses.

Comment: Fichtre, rétrogradé pour ça ? En l'absence de règles explicites émanant d'un organisme de normalisation universellement accepté, le mieux qu'on puisse faire pour renseigner quelqu'un sur la tournure à choisir est de donner un avis basé sur son expérience et appréciation individuelle, adapté au contexte en question. Non ? Perso, je ne sens aucune différence dans l'usage courant. Appréciation individuelle. Je suis aussi d'avis que dans un contexte formel/solennel le "Désolé" en début de phrase ne passe pas, mais la question ne vise qu'à départager deux expressions "non formelles"...

Comment: Il s'agit en effet d'expériences personnelles multiples sur un sujet hors académismes et autres connaissances strictement livresques. Le problème vient de l'accentuation/l'imposition d'un point de vue qui rejette indirectement les autres (source du ‘moinssoyé’)… ce qui n'apparaît pas dans votre commentaire :-) . Les deux références citées dans mon commentaire situé sous la question sont tirées du Petit Robert, et donc "more formal", d'autres réponses contextualisent le problème … laissons *@Hilal Aouam* se faire une idée.

Comment: "Le problème vient de l'accentuation/l'imposition d'un point de vue qui rejette indirectement les autres" -> C'est le cas de toutes les réponses, non ? Je ne vois personne qui ait avancé de réponse suffixée d'un "mais j'dis ça j'dis rien, considérez également toutes les autres options possibles". 'fin bref, effectivement votre commentaire et celui de jillagre devraient suffire. Par contre si le vôtre est sourcé du Robert il faudrait l'indiquer ; je n'en ai pas vu mention. *All being said*, je conteste toujours le moinssoiement. C'est abusé, m'sieur.

Comment: Justement non, toutes les réponses ne cherchent pas à imposer le point de vue de leur auteur. Les modérateurs du site sont déjà intervenus pour des personnes qui voulaient avoir, et raison, et le dernier mot. C'est la principale motivation de mon intervention dans votre réponse. Le site demande que la réponse soit éditée pour que je puisse annuler mon vote. Il n'y a pas urgence à reformuler sans précipitation votre réponse en l'enrichissant de nos échanges.

Comment: J'ai toujours du mal à voir en quoi ma réponse cherchait à "imposer un point de vue" ou caractérisait une volonté d'avoir raison et le dernier mot... à la limite, j'aurais compris si le motif était "réponse non sourcée". M'enfin bref.

Comment: Tout cela serait déjà éclairci dans l'oralité … pour simplifier, vous est-il possible de réécrire votre réponse sans *je* et sans lettres grasses, tout en exprimant qu'il  vous est naturel d'utiliser l'un ou l'autre terme … subordonner le français à la pure logique éloigne le « glamour » qui en fait son charme :-)